# Can Azure Function Bindings take a folder instead of a file as path

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Currently I need to read data from different files in a folder and return the result. There are quite a large number of files in the folder. So is it possible to use the folder as path in Azure function bindings??[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the workaround that is possible using HTTP Trigger.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<YOUR ACCOUNT NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<YOUR SAS TOKEN>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    blobnames=""
    
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Enter the container you are searching for")
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name') 
                       
    print("\nList blobs in the container")
    generator = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name=name) #lists the blobs inside containers
    for blob in generator:
        blobnames+=blob.name+"\n"

    if name:        
            return func.HttpResponse(f"{blobnames}"
        )
        
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "There is no container present with this name",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was looking for the feasibility of azure function bindings. I have already implemented a similar solution for the workaround.